# SQL Server duplicate results to query after inner join

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I have a query where I call from 7 tables. In my query I connect the tables with inner join.

The problem is that I have duplicate results. I want to mention that I don’t have any duplicate records in my tables. I tried distinct but it doesn't help.

Also I tried with Group by and again it d. Do you have any suggestions? IS this a common problem when you call from many tables with foreign keys?

Comment: Well... how about you show us your query?

Comment: You most likely have a one-to-many relationship between some of your tables which is causing what appears to be duplicates. Without seeing your tables and some data it would be difficult.

Comment: What you perceive as duplicates are not.  Return all clolumns from every joined table and you will quickly see why they are not "true duplicates"

Comment: So what do you suggest XQbert?

Comment: @Equilibrium If I tell you my car is broken and expect you to fix it over the internet how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the select list to show each PK of all tables in your query, look and see which PK value is repeating, this is your duplicate.  Look in the query around that table's join.  I'll bet that your joining wrong, something like this:

```
SELECT
    a.PK, b.Pk, c.PK, D.pk .....
    FROM Table_A             a
        INNER JOIN Table_B   b ON a.col=b.pk
        INNER JOIN Table_C   c ON b.col=b.pk --<<look for a bad join like this
        INNER JOIN Table_D   d ON c.col=d.pk
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem solved. I had bad joins in my query.